# How can I join two dataframes with different dtypes?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe(df1) with index as a date range and no columns specified and another dataframe(df2) with float values in every column.
I tried joining a specific column from df2 to df1 using .join()  method and ended up with all values as NaN in df1. What should I do to solve this?

Comment: Code says more than a thousand words. We can help you better if you show the code that fails.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you mean without any example of the data or their shape, and without more details about what kind of 'join' you're trying to do. It sounds like you are trying to concatenate dataframes without relying on a column or index level names to join on. That's what `join` or `merge` try to do, so if you don't have common values on the `on` parameter of the `join`, you'll end up with `nan`s. If I'm correct and you just want a concatenation of dataframes, then you can use `concat`. I can't provide the code without more details, but it would look something like this:

```
new_df = pd.concat([df1, df2[['whatever_column_you_want_to_concatenate']]], axis=1)
```